# Functions, Conditional Statements, and entry level questions

Tags: python

Im brand new to coding: Im taking a course that has a coding element and Im already falling behind. Im trying to create a conditional statement. You enter month, day and year and my code reports the day of the week(Sunday-Monday). The first functions comes from month and year:

```
def first_g(m):
    if m= 1 or 2:
        m=y-1
        return m

    else: return y

first_g(1)=
```

I keep getting `SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`. I don't know what that means. I have to code an additional function and then put both functions into an equation that I already have. Bonus question if you have read this far: 17%15 only returns my file name in the terminal when it should be returning 2. I understand my question is probably full of errors, but I'm already too late to drop this course. Any help would be appreciated

m==1 or 2, m:= 1 or 2. I need a basic tutorial on conditional statements and functions. I've watched these two YouTube videos but I think someone pointing out what Im doing wrong would be more helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QpZ1Y4v824
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91dTO8VXiys&t=1s

I would like someone to point out what isnt working and the language I need to address them in Python.

Comment: You wrote `first_g(1)=`, I don't know what that means. Why did you put a `=` here?

Comment: The error is caused by first_g(1)= . You should assign a name to / print the returned value from the function call or otherwise do something with that value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i can see syntax error stated as 'SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call'. This is because of incorrect use of comparison operator '=', you should use '=='.
Also you are trying to return 'y' but you have not defined 'y'.

```
def first_g(m, y):
    if m == 1 or m == 2:
        return y-1
    else:
        return y
```

Comment: While the use of `=` is indeed incorrect, that is not the cause of the error.

Comment: I can only see couple of reasons for this error. 1) incorrect conditional operator 2) Unresolved variable, I do not see 'y' assigned before you are using it. Can you resolve those first and check?

Comment: Say that to OP, not me. I'm telling you that the use of `=` in this conditional statement is not the cause of the "*cannot assign to function call*" error, although it is also a `SyntaxError` on its own.

Comment: Ok leave that aside, again at the end of your code where you have called the function, you are storing it's value in a variable. so keep the variable on LHS and function on RHS....   'variable_name =  first_g(1)'. This is also the reason for that error.